# How Do I make access to automatically update multiple fields in one table based on the value of a field from another table?

Tags: database, ms-access, relationship

So I have two tables in my database:
**A**: "Daily activities"
**B**: "list of beneficiaries"

**A** has multiple fields as you can see in the picture:
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/XMvic.png

likewise, **B** has its own fields:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9IQ8Y.png

As you can see,  both the table share 3 fields together namely, “case_no”, “names” and “nature of case” . now I can assign look up fields that will let me take the values from one table to another, but I don't want that.
I want to input the case no in the table **A** and want the access to automatically fill up the next two fields “name” and “nature of case” by pulling the respective data from its sister table,**B** based on the value of the given case no. is that possible? If so how can I achieve that? thanks in advance!

Comment: This type of design is not recommended with access. All you really need to do in table B is include your primary key from table A. Now table B has a direct link to everything you need.  Having the same exact data in multiple tables is poor design in a relational database.

Comment: my main purpose to have such a behavior in my DB was so that I didn't have to input the exactly same data in two different tables. like you said, having the primary field in table A related to B in one-to-many relationship really did the job for me. I can totally produce the desired reports by adding a bunch of fields from A and the others from B. thanks for putting me in the right direction! @Gene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks to the above tip-off from @Gene, I managed to achieve the results I wanted this whole thing to work in the first place. a little awkward, yes but really helpful.  : )